# TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_page' of undefined [Laravel Pagination]

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i'm creating a Pagination in laravel using Vue.js but its give me an error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_page' of undefined**

Code in template

```
<pre>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page_item" :class="{disable: !pagination.first_link}">
                        <a href="#" class="page-link" @click="fetchUser(pagination.first_link)">&laquo;</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page_item" :class="{disable: !pagination.prev_link}">
                        <a href="#" class="page-link" @click="fetchUser(pagination.prev_link)">&lt;</a>
                    </li>
                    <li  v-for="n in pagination.last_page" :key=n class="page_item" :class="{actve: pagination.current_page == n}">
                        <a href="#" class="page-link" @click="fetchUser(pagination.path_page + n)">{{n}}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page_item" :class="{disable: !pagination.next_link}">
                        <a href="#" class="page-link" @click="fetchUser(pagination.next_link)">&gt;</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page_item" :class="{disable: !pagination.last_link}">
                        <a href="#" class="page-link" @click="fetchUser(pagination.last_link)">&raquo;</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            Page: {{ pagination.from_page }} - {{ pagination.to_page}}
            Total: {{ pagination.total_page }}
        </div>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Vue.js file

```
<pre>
      fetchUser(pagi) {
        let $this = this;
        pagi = pagi || '/api/users';
        axios.get(pagi).then(function(response) {
            $this.users = response.data;    
            $this.pagination = {
                current_page: response.meta.current_page,
                last_page: response.meta.last_page,
                from_page: response.meta.from,
                to_page: response.meta.to,
                total_page: response.meta.total,
                path_page: response.meta.path + '?page=',
                first_link: response.links.first,
                last_link: response.links.last,
                prev_link: response.links.prev,
                next_link: response.links.next,
            };
         }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }) 
      }
</pre>
```

I'll appreciate of all your help.
Thanks in advances...

Comment: Can you `console.log(response.meta)` before `$this.pagination`

Comment: okay, i'll try..

Comment: its got  undefined.

Comment: So you don't have meta in your response... And can you `console.log(response)` maybe is other name or something.

Comment: i console.log(response) i saw there is meta
but when i'll try console.log(response.meta) its give me undefined

Comment: Can you put screenshot in your question or paste what you get?

Comment: it solved..
i changed all response.meta to response.data.meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the value of "response.meta.current_page" and "response.meta.last_page", I think they are empty or with a value that is notassociated with current_page. Try to put a number in that fields and research with that.